# What are frames in an Image Stream?

Tags: java, android

I am reading over the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) for `SurfaceTexture`. Specifically, it states:

> SurfaceTexture captures frames from an image stream as an OpenGL ES texture. The
>   image stream may come from either camera preview or video decode. A
>   Surface created from a SurfaceTexture can be used as an output
>   destination for the android.hardware.camera2 API

But there is no explanation as to what a frame is. My understanding of streams are the I/O streams where you have a sequences of bytes that you can read from (InputStream) or write to (OutputStream). Are frames a synonym for bytes or are they a distinct feature of I/O streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [Frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(video)) are the still images that compose the video. One picture is one frame. A video (in the US) is usually 30 frames per second. Other countries use other standards (for example, PAL is 25 frames per second). At least in modern times, pre-HD it was "fields" (not "frames") and two "fields" made one "frame".